# s3proxy in a closed kubernetes network

Tags: kubernetes, azure-blob-storage, s3proxy

I'm using an s3proxy to manage s3 api to blob storage.
It's used by mongodb to store backup.

I'm installing s3proxy with RADAR-Base/s3proxy helm chart with this values file

```
s3:
  identity: $S3_PROXY_ID
  credential: $S3_PROXY_CRED

target:
  provider: azureblob
  endpoint: $S3_PROXY_AZURE_ENDPOINT
  identity: $S3_PROXY_AZURE_ID
  credential: $S3_PROXY_AZURE_CRED
```

everything works fined with a port-forward of the s3proxy service and using aws cli

```
➜  deployment git:(main) ✗ k port-forward -n s3proxy svc/s3proxy-s3-proxy 8000:80                      
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8000 -> 80
Forwarding from [::1]:8000 -> 80
puis que je tape dessus avec aws cli j'ai une bonne sortie
➜  deployment git:(main) ✗ aws s3 ls s3://mycontainer --endpoint http://localhost:8000
2024-02-06 16:20:16         66 fruits.json
```

but When I tried to do it in a pod I'm getting a forbidden http error

```
sh-5.1# echo $SECRET_KEY
s3proxy
sh-5.1# echo $ACCESS_KEY
s3proxy
sh-5.1# mc alias set my-s3 http://s3proxy-s3-proxy.s3proxy.svc.cluster.local ACCESS_KEY SECRET_KEY
```

(I tried to wget to check if it was the dns resolution that might cause the issue, but it resolves with a 403 forbidden)

(yes I'm using s3proxy as an access and secret key)

I thought it might be due to cors origines.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to use `--api s3v4`.